# Why do I get an 'undefined' item after Array.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, reduce

I am trying to learn JavaScript. Now, I am doing experiments with arrays, JSON objects and the sort and reduce methods. The experiment is to find a nice solution to Codility.com's NumberOfDiscIntersections task. I have seen the solution around, and I am trying to reproduce mine, so that I actually get the method.

My current code is almost done. What I ask here is: **why am I getting a last 'undefined' element in the output of the execution of the following code?**

This is the exact JavaScript code:

```js
C = [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3];
answer = solution(C);
console.log(answer);

//circle radius varies from 0..2147483647
function solution(A) {
  //marker = {spot:0, openers:0, closers:0};
  const N = A.length;
  const points = [];
  let left = 0;
  let right = 0;

  // First, I count all borders
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    left = i - A[i];
    right = i + A[i];
    points.push({
      "position": left,
      "openers": 1,
      "closers": 0
    });
    points.push({
      "position": right,
      "openers": 0,
      "closers": 1
    });
  }
  console.log("points before sort:")
  for (item of points) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  points.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.position < b.position) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.position > b.position) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log("points after sort:")
  for (item of points) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  let parseable = points.reduce((acc, object) => {
    var index = acc.map((o) => o.position).indexOf(object.position);
    if (index == -1) {
      acc.push(object);
    } else {
      acc[index].openers += object.openers;
      acc[index].closers += object.closers;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  console.log("points after reduce:")
  for (item of parseable) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Thia is my console output:

> points before sort:
> position: -2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 2, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 0, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 2, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 1, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 3, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 0, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 6, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 6, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 8, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> points after sort:
> position: -2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 0, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 0, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 1, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 2, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 2, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 3, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 6, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 6, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 8, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> points after reduce:
> position: -2, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 0, openers: 2, closers: 0 }
> position: 1, openers: 1, closers: 0 }
> position: 2, openers: 2, closers: 2 }
> position: 3, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> position: 6, openers: 0, closers: 2 }
> position: 8, openers: 0, closers: 1 }
> undefined

Why do I have this 'undefined' item in the end of the reduced array?

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Change `for (item of parseable) {
    console.log(item);
  }` to `return parseable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything from the `solution` function.

`answer` variable has default value `undefined`, which is the one getting logged in the console.

```
answer = solution(C); // `answer` is `undefined`
console.log(answer); // logs `undefined`
```

`return` something from the function, which `answer` variable can hold.

thanks

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it.

I did not reach the end yet and forgot I had added the extra commands for me to be able to test it in my machine before doing the submission in Codility.com.

It takes too long for every submission and evaluation process.